# The usage of ValuePrimitive in Kendo-ComboBox

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

What is the real advantage of valuePrimitive attribute in kendo-combobox angular.
I need the advantages of this attribute with some code examples of this attribute using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it depends on your model, for example

imagine you have a form with two combos.

the Object for the form would be like

```
{ Combo1:{value:1,text:"One"}, Combo2:{value:3,text:"Three"}}
```

but in your post you need to send only the ids

```
{ Combo1:1, Combo2:3}
```

It would be simpler to store only the primitive and send back only the ids.

In my cases I have objects with related objects and with enums, my enums are displayed with a combo set to  ValuePrimitive.